# FInd Current location in android tablet

Tags: android, geolocation, gps

What is the best way to find the current user location in android tablet which does not have a SIM?

My question could be naive but does the Location Manager requires network operator(SIM) and the internet connection? Similarly, if we have to use GPS, does it also need a network operator?

Please advise.

Comment: I get your question, but I think that some of the guys below (especially the one that -1 your question) didn't. I +1 your question to compensate :-)  If I understand correctly, you're asking how would google know your location if your GPS is off, and you have no cellular connectivity (no cell tower info). I'm asking the same thing. Let me know if you figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a network operator for GPS.

You do need Internet connectivity to use the NETWORK_PROVIDER though. Without Internet connection you won't get an updated position.

The NETWORK_PROVIDER gathers wifi station information and cell tower information and sends that to Google's location server via the Internet. The location server uses that information to find the most likely position of the user, based on data that it has stored in the server's databases.

You can access the Internet via wifi or mobile data. If you don't have a SIM-card, NETWORK_PROVIDER will just gather wifi information and try to guess your location based on that.

Answer (score 2):

you dont actually need network operator for GPS

Answer (score 1):

The `LocationManager` class uses the internal GPS radio, not your SIM card.  You also don't need an internet connection unless you plan on using a `MapView` or similar map component.  If you have a GPS in your tablet, just turn it on (activate it) and try one of the many examples using `LocationManager`, `or`SensorManager` to read from your GPS sensor.  Hope this helps!  Here is an [example](http://hejp.co.uk/android/android-gps-example/) to get you started.